# How to make correct BD for book store based on Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

Look, I have book shop, I need it DB to have books with some fields like title, price, description. The problem is I can not correctly organize it.

How to make it correct? Like I can put description into DB as varchar(500) but it won`t be correct.

Also the question is should I use mySQL or MongoDB? I heard Mongo is better for small online shops.

Answer (score 0):

I will put one situation when MongoDB can be usually. Somehow in a simple explain, Collections in MongoDB are similar to Tables in MySQL. In MySQL in can tell each row as Tuple, in MongoDB we call it as Document. A Document in MongoDB is similar to JSON object, something like this:

Users Documents

```
{
    name: 'foo',
    age: 20
}
```

In the user's collections we can to have a lot of documents, each documents with specific structure and properties. In this scenario MongoDB can be a good choice, and I think this is your case.